# Spring Controller returns unformatted json

Tags: java, json, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, jackson

I have configured my application to return html, json or xml views.
html and xml views are fine but there is a problem with the json views.

The returned json is always prefixed with an "{} &&"

example

```
{} && {"asd":{"name":"Practical Spring LDAP","isbn":"978-1475265453","author":"Balaji Varanasi"}}
```

my spring configuration to render the views is

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
      <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
          <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
          <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
          <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"/> 
        </map>
      </property>
      <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
          <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
            <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
          </bean>
        </list>
      </property>
      <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
          <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
            <property name="prefixJson" value="true"/>
          </bean>

          <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">  
             <constructor-arg>  
                 <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">  
                     <property name="classesToBeBound">  
                         <list>  
                             <value>com.sam.beans.Book</value>  
                          </list>  
                     </property>  
                 </bean>  
             </constructor-arg>  
         </bean>  
        </list>
      </property>
    </bean>
```

sample controller

```
@RequestMapping("/getBook")
public String showBook(Model model)  
{  
    model.addAttribute("book", new Book("Practical Spring LDAP", "978-1475265453", "Balaji Varanasi"));  

    return "book";  
}
```

help needed...

UPDATE: adding class definition for Book

```
@XmlRootElement(name="book")  
public class Book  
{  
    private String name;  
    private String isbn;  
    private String author;  

    public Book()  
    {  

    }  

    public Book(String name, String isbn, String author)  
    {  
        this.name = name;  
        this.isbn = isbn;  
        this.author = author;  
    }  

    public String getName() {  
        return name;  
    }  
    public void setName(String name) {  
        this.name = name;  
    }  
    public String getIsbn() {  
        return isbn;  
    }  
    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {  
        this.isbn = isbn;  
    }  
    public String getAuthor() {  
        return author;  
    }  
    public void setAuthor(String author) {  
        this.author = author;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Can we see the class definition for Book?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

now am using ModelAndView and in the view i give MappingJacksonJsonView.

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(new MappingJacksonJsonView(),"book", new Book("Practical Spring LDAP", "978-1475265453", "Balaji Varanasi"));
```

not sure what was the problem with using just Model.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ResponseBody` with return type for function serving the request.

```
@RequestMapping("/getBook")
public @ReponseBody 
String showBook(Model model)  
{  
    model.addAttribute("book", new Book("Practical Spring LDAP", "978-1475265453", "Balaji Varanasi"));  

    return "book";  
}
```